# Performant Fog-of-War With Sight Blocking in Unity

Tags: unity, c#, fog-of-war

In games like Command & Conquer or Age of Empires, players can't see all of the map.  Terrain and enemies are revealed only when the player has soldiers nearby.

As I understand it, the most performant way of doing this is by representing map visibility as a grid of cells.  When a unit moves into a new cell it updates all cells within a circle shape around the unit.

However, I would like to know how to integrate sight blocking.  What I mean by this, is that if a cell is occupied by something which a unit can't see past (like a wall) all cells behind the wall are covered by fog-of-war.

[Here's a YouTube video of what it should look like](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vcYCab1vl1E).  The author doesn't go into how they did it, aside from mentioning "brute force shadow casting".

Comment: The author of that video gives a [step-by-step breakdown in this Tumblr post](https://toasticusprime.tumblr.com/post/76866153394/hey-i-saw-your-unit-fog-of-war-algorithm-on), which might be useful to you.

Comment: @DMGregory I think that may have answered my question.

Comment: Sweet! If you get it working, it would be great to add an answer here yourself, so it's easier for future users working on similar issues to search for.

Comment: I am working on a performant implementation of a Fog of War, checkout my twitter https://twitter.com/arielsan, my idea is to make a blog post about the it at some point but if you see something that could help you could ask me directly. I will try to answer the question too.

Answer (score 1):

Basically what I do is, for each pixel in vision range, I go pixel by pixel and check a line to the center (using the [Bresenham's line algorithm](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Bitmap/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm#C.23)), if there is no obstacle, then the pixel is visible, otherwise, it is blocked.

It works pretty well, ~100 units at 60fps, check out [this tweet](https://twitter.com/arielsan/status/1025899244950089733) to see it working. I plan to write a blog post to explain in detail the implementation.

Don't know if that works for you as an answer.

Comment: I completed the second blog post about what I am using, not sure if it would be of much help but here it is: https://twitter.com/arielsan/status/1065029151508320256